# Trying to rename Individual Excel Objects in powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I create reports in powerpoint where the graphs/tables within the report are created from underlying excel sheets embedded as objects within the powerpoint.  When I open these files, each file has the exact same name, which is the name of the powerpoint presentation/file.  Is there a way to change the name of each underlying excel object to something unique?

I am doing this so that I can copy data from subscription reports to the powerpoint presentation via python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window title is not the file name. Embedded Excel objects are renamed to "Microsoft_Excel_Worksheet.xlsx", "Microsoft_Excel_Worksheet1.xlsx", etc. and are stored in the ppt/embeddings folder in the XML. It's not possible to change this behavior.

However, if you link the Excel rather than embed, the original file name is retained and that file name displays on the top of the Excel window. The path and file name are stored in PowerPoint.

Comment: John, Thank you very much for your answer.  Based on your explanation, how can i open/view a specific embedded Excel file within the PPT presentation, to determine the full '...xlsx' file name/extension name?  Thanks again!

Comment: If you download and install the free 7-Zip utility, you can right-click on your PowerPoint file and choose Open Archive. Then you can view the contents of the embeddings folder and file names in it. https://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: Thanks John, unfortunately this is a work computer and i cannot download programs due to our firewall.  Any other ways of identifying the full extension of the underlying excel objects?

Comment: Make a copy of the file to a separate folder, add .zip to the end, respond to the message about chaning the file ending, then right-click and unzip the file. Open the ppt folder, then inside that the embeddings folder. The Excel files will be there.

Comment: John thank you so much!  i was having trouble following your exact instructions, but i was able to google from the directions you gave me.  i found this, http://feedback.dominknow.com/knowledgebase/articles/15093-how-do-i-extract-audio-files-that-are-embedded-in and it works perfectly.  thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, it hard to write a clear set of steps in these comments. Thanks for the upvote!